# Stata: DFL Decomposition and Bootstrapping with Complex Survey design

Tags: stata, statistics-bootstrap

Hello I am trying to do a DFL style reweighting with bootstrap weights and SEs. I have a 2 stage stratified sample over 5 rounds (repeated cross section).

The idea is to create counterfactual weights for the reference population and then find the difference in mean outcomes for the two groups. This difference can be divided into three parts
Total difference (group 1 - group 2 , both using survey weights)
Explained difference (group 2 using counterfactual weights- group 2 using survey weights)
Unexplained difference (group 1 using survey weights- group 2 using counterfactual weights)

I have written the following program for the same

Code:

```
///to make sure there is no singleton strata
egen cluster_id= group(sector state region strat fsu)
egen stratum_id= group(sector state region strat)

foreach r in 1 2 3 4 5 {
preserve
qui keep if round==`r'
qui svyset cluster_id [pw=hhwt] , strata (startum_id)
qui unique cluster_id, by (startum_id) gen (dup)
qui by startum_id, sort: egen temp= total(dup)
count if temp==1
drop if temp==1  
drop temp dup
save "C:\Users\Round 2 Data\bs_round`r'", replace
restore
}
```

Code:

```
///final data we will use
use "C:\Users\Round 2 Data\bs_round1"
foreach r in 2 3 4 5 {
qui merge m:m round using "C:\Users\Round 2 Data\bs_round`r'"
drop _merge
sort round
tab round
}
save "C:\Users\Round 2 Data\bs_all"
```

Code:

```
///constructing bootstrap weights
egen pooled_cid= group (cluster_id round)
egen pooled_sid= group (stratum_id round)

svyset  pooled_cid [pw=hhwt], strata( pooled_sid)
bsweights bsw, reps(100) n(-1)  
svyset  pooled_cid [pw=hhwt], strata( pooled_sid) bsrweight(bsw*) vce(bootstrap)
```

Code:

```
///writing the program
#delimit ;

capture program drop mydfl;
program define mydfl, eclass properties (svyb);
version 13;
args wgtname xvars outcome;

    gen groupref=(group==1);
    egen countg1=sum(group==1);
    egen countg2=sum(group==2);
    logit groupref `xvars';
    predict phatref;
    gen `wgtname'2=(phatref/(1-phatref))*(countg2/countg1) if group==2;
    replace `wgtname'2=1 if group==1;
    gen `wgtname'1=((1-phatref)/phatref)*(countg1/countg2) if group==1;
    replace `wgtname'1=1 if group==2;
    drop phatref groupref countg*;
                forvalues i=1/2 {;
                                sum `wgtname'`i' if group==`i';
                                  replace `wgtname'`i' = `wgtname'`i' / r(mean) if group==`i';
                  };

    mean `outcome' if group==1 ;
    mat diff_1=e(b) ;
    mean `outcome' if group==2  ;
    mat diff_2=e(b) ;
    mean `outcome' if group==2 [pw=`wgtname'2] ;
    mat diff_3=e(b) ;

    mat dd_t = diff_1-diff_2 ;
    mat dd_e= diff_3-diff_2 ;
    mat dd_u= diff_1-diff_3 ;

    ereturn scalar dd_tot=e1(dd_t,1,1) ;
    ereturn scalar dd_exp=e1(dd_e,1,1) ;
    ereturn scalar dd_unex=e1(dd_u,1,1) ;

end;
```

Code:

```
///running the program
local xvars age i.state fhead yrs_ed marital rural
local outcome wage

svy bootstrap e(dd_tot) e(dd_exp) e(dd_unex): mydfl wtid "`xvars'" `outcome'
```

I want to find the standard error for the mean gap, mean explained gap and mean unexplained gap in outcome-in this case wage of the two groups.

I keep getting the following error (after the program creates wtid1 and wtid2)

```
    Bootstrap replications (100)
----+--- 1 ---+--- 2 ---+--- 3 ---+--- 4 ---+--- 5 
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    50
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   100
insufficient observations to compute bootstrap standard errors
no results will be saved
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also posted on http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1309830-dfl-decomposition-and-bootstrapping-with-complex-survey-design

Comment: Why is `wgtname` enclosed in double quotes when you call to `mydfl`? Also, I think you have larger issues here (although  I could be wrong) by passing a local which contains more than one element as an argument to a program that uses `args`. I suspect this will not pass the arguments to the program as you intend.

Comment: `wgtname` is the name I want to give to the variable that the program will create. This isn't a predefined variable but one that will be created.

Comment: Ok, well regardless, I *think* when you execute `mydfl "'wgtname'" 'xvars' 'outcome'` Stata will pass `mydfl wtid age i.state2 ... rural wage`. and your program only takes 3 `args`, so only `wtid` `age` and `i.state2` will be used. So in the program when you run `logit groupref 'xvars'`, the actual command being executed will be `logit groupref age`.

Comment: You would need to enclose `'xvars'` in double quotes when you call to `mydfl` so that all the elements of `xvars` get passed to the program as a single argument.

Comment: Thank you. That was indeed one of the issues. However even now the program is producing an error. I've updated the question to reflect the new error it is producing.

Answer (score 1):

A certain cause of bootstrap failure is that the program creates permanent variables.

Here is the first `generate` statement:

```
  gen groupref=(group==1);
```

`bootstrap` first runs the program on the entire data set, and the variable `groupref` is added.  Next, the first bootstrap replica is drawn, and the program is run on that replicate.  The `generate` statement will now silently fail because the variable already exists. The entire program will therefore fail and the only indication will be the "X" in the Stata results.

The solution is to designate all variables created by `generate`, `egen`, or `predict` as *temporary* variables. These will be dropped after each replicate is analyzed. Here is the usage:

```
tempvar groupref;
gen `groupref' = (group==1);
```

`tempvar` is a local macro and can take a list of names. Similar macros are `tempname` and `tempfile`.